# IIS and argv[0] path syntax

Tags: c++, iis, iis-6, iis-5

I am working on a dll for IIS 5 written in C++ (the webserver of microsoft)

but I see something strange when debugging, in my `main()` function

`argc = 1`
and `argv[0] = "\\?\C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Project\Project.dll"`

**what is this syntax?**

It's not exactly easy to search on google !

My code behind, which is also embeded in an executable, was not expecting such a path and is not working anymore.

Comment: Ahh, welcome to the wonders of Windows, NTFS and SMB. :-)

Comment: Do you see the same in release version?

Comment: I think it's called an "[extended-length path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247\(v=vs.85\).aspx#maxpath)"

Comment: @user786653 you mind making an answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [extended-length path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) to allow paths of greater length than `MAX_PATH`.